# how to avoid the loops in a specific multiple conditional statement in R

Tags: r, performance, loops, bigdata

I am using R to make inference from electronic medical records(EMRs) in R. Actually I do write a loop command that can work, but the problem is the loop can be really slow when dealing with millions of EMRs. So could anyone transform my commands into a faster way (maybe a vector based computing or other possible ways) ?
My purpose is to figure out whether a set of commodities(in this case, they are from p324 to p9274) contains either of a set of characters(in this case, they are I25.2, I21. and I22.).
here is a sample of my data:

```
test <- data.frame(p324 = c("I24.001", "I10.x04", "I48.x02", "I48.x01", "I25.201", "I25.201", "I25.101", "I25.101", "NA", "I50", "I25.101", "I25.101", "I25.101", "I45.102", "I50.902"),
p327 = c("I20.000", "K76.000", "E11.900", "I44.200", "NA", "I49.904", "I45.102", "I50.910", "NA", "I10  05", "J98.402", "NA", "NA", "R57.0", "I10.x04"),
p3291 = c("I50.903", "K80.100", "N39.000", "I25.103", "NA", "I50.908", "NA", "I10  04", "NA", "I25.101", "I10  03", "NA", "NA", "I25.101", "I10.x05"),
p3294 = c("I10.x05", "K76.807", "J98.414", "K81.100", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "J43", "I10.x06"),
p3297 = c("NA", "I83.900", "E87.801", "NA", "NA", "I21.620", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "I10.x07"),
p3281 = c("K80.100", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "I10.x08"),
p3284 = c("K76.807", "I21.620", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "I10.x09"),
p3287 = c("I83.900", "I10.x3", "I10.x2", "I10.x1", "I10.x0", "I10.x1", "I10.x2", "I10.x3", "I10.x4", "I10.x5", "I10.x6", "I10.x7", "I10.x8", "I10.x9", "I10.x10"),
p3271 = c("I50.908", "NA", "I10.x1", "I10.x0", "I10.x1", "I10.x2", "I10.x3", "I10.x4", "I10.x5", "I10.x6", "I10.x7", "I10.x8", "I10.x9", "I10.x10", "I10.x11"),
p3274 = c("NA", "I10.x1", "I10.x0", "I10.x1", "I10.x2", "I10.x3", "I10.x4", "I10.x5", "I10.x6", "I10.x7", "I10.x8", "I10.x9", "I10.x10", "I10.x11", "I10.x12"))
```

Here is my code:

```
for (i in 1:15)
{
  if (any(
    c(
      substr(test$p324[i], 1, 5),
      substr(test$p327[i], 1, 5),
      substr(test$p3291[i], 1, 5),
      substr(test$p3294[i], 1, 5),
      substr(test$p3297[i], 1, 5),
      substr(test$p3281[i], 1, 5),
      substr(test$p3284[i], 1, 5),
      substr(test$p3287[i], 1, 5),
      substr(test$p3271[i], 1, 5),
      substr(test$p3274[i], 1, 5)
    ) %in% c("I25.2")
  ) |
  any(
    c(
      substr(test$p324[i], 1, 4),
      substr(test$p327[i], 1, 4),
      substr(test$p3291[i], 1, 4),
      substr(test$p3294[i], 1, 4),
      substr(test$p3297[i], 1, 4),
      substr(test$p3281[i], 1, 4),
      substr(test$p3284[i], 1, 4),
      substr(test$p3287[i], 1, 4),
      substr(test$p3271[i], 1, 4),
      substr(test$p3274[i], 1, 4)
    ) %in% c("I21.", "I22.")
  ))
  test$MI[i] = 1
  else
    test$MI[i] = 0
}
```

So, can anyone transform my commands, or give me some suggestions so that, it could operate efficiently and fast even when the cases are more than 1 million? Thanks so much.

Comment: I compared the codes that use `sapply & grepl()` by @Sixiang.Hu, `grepl()` by @David Arenburg, and `substr` by @David Arenburg, it appears that the `sapply` code has the best performance. Here are the results of my tests:

Comment: Please see my updated about my question. I timed each code and checked the results. It appeared that substr by @David Arenburg generates inconsistent results. I am not sure the reason why.

Comment: Probably because `grepl` finds more than just the exact matches. My guess you have some wrong matches there. I would check your results to see if you get the correctly. Also, your first variation doesn't match what was provided in the answer, for instance, there is no `as.data.frame(t(test))` there. Finally, you don't have to run `unlist(test)` twice, you could store it and reuse.

Comment: @David Arenburg Thanks for your benchmarking results. I tested these three methods based on my empirical dataset, with 523,441 observations, and I don't know how can I give this data to you to check the reasons for generating these NA values by the substr operator. I made some minor revisions to the sapply/grepl function for my dataset and I don't think it is the reason for outperforming the substr codes. Even though I stored `unlist(test)`, `sapply & grepl()` (5.062496 secs) still outperform `substr` (7.068666 secs) and `grepl()` (12.69934 secs) on my dataset. I am checking for the reasons.

Comment: @David Arenburg I think I have figured out the reason for these NA values. The problem is when the data contains NA values, the `substr` operation will generate NA values, while the `grepl` operation could generate the right results. I also updated the benchmark results based on my data and I think you are right, although in my result, it shows that    David(3.728264) > SixHu(4.323772) > SixHuVec(11.867062).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are looking for performance improvement:

1. Don't run loops by row (`sapply` is also a loop)
2. Don't run vectorized operations in a loop (why are you running `substr` by row by column when you can just run it once?)
3. Avoid using regex- it is slow. Instead, if you are dealing with exact matches here, just use `==` or `%in%`.

Here is a simple vectorized possible solution for your problem

```
res <- (substr(unlist(test), 1, 5) == "I25.2") | 
       (substr(unlist(test), 1, 4) %in% c("I21.", "I22."))
dim(res) <- dim(test)
test$MI <- rowSums(res)
```

This is basically ran `substr(test, k, n)` only once for each `k`/`n` combo (which is 2 in total) and compared against the values in interest. Then, (because `%in%` doesn't have a `data.frame` method) we transformed the resulting vector into the correct format again and summed the matches per row (in a vecotrized manner). The result is how many matches per row. If you like, it could be very easily transformed into binary (also in a vectroized manner)

---

**Benchmarks**

So OP mentioned benchmarks, so here are some benchmarks done on 10K/10 rows/columns

1. The `grepl`/`sapply` solution is about X10 slower than the vecotrized ones
2. My suggestion to vectorize the `grepl` solution improves performance by about X10 times
3. My own solution performs very similarly to the vectorized grepl solution, while I believe it will generalize much better as the regex will become more complex (for additional matches), while `%in%` has almost no marginal cost for additional mathces

*Setup* (using OPs `test` data)

```
set.seed(123)
big.df <- as.data.frame(matrix(sample(unlist(test, use.names = FALSE), 1e5, replace = TRUE), ncol = 10))

# sapply / grepl
SixHu <- function(df) { 
  t_test <- as.data.frame(t(df))
  chk <- function(x){
    grepl("I25\\.2|I21\\.|I22\\.",x)
  }
  unname(colSums(sapply(t_test, chk)))
}

# Vectorized grepl
SixHuVec <- function(df) { 
  res <- grepl("I25\\.2|I21\\.|I22\\.", unlist(df))
  dim(res) <- dim(df) 
  rowSums(res)
}

# Vectorized substr
David <- function(df) { 
  tmp <- unlist(df)
  res <- (substr(tmp, 1, 5) == "I25.2") | (substr(tmp, 1, 4) %in% c("I21.", "I22."))
  dim(res) <- dim(df)
  rowSums(res)
}
```

*Validation*

```
identical(SixHu(test), SixHuVec(test))
## [1] TRUE
identical(SixHu(test), David(test))
## [1] TRUE
```

*Benchmark Results*

```
microbenchmark::microbenchmark(SixHu(big.df),
                               SixHuVec(big.df),
                               David(big.df))
# Unit: milliseconds
#             expr       min         lq       mean     median        uq       max neval cld
#    SixHu(big.df) 989.55655 1021.17121 1047.63956 1041.94771 1062.7705 1151.4196   100   b
# SixHuVec(big.df)  67.52131   72.39233   84.61193   75.31462   85.5352  147.0646   100  a 
#    David(big.df)  63.48242   68.20945   88.73896   75.19159  115.3958  147.0867   100  a
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions!Since I am just a beginner in R, loop is the most intuitive way for me to write codes. I run substr by row and by column because actually I have more than 200 variables and I just want to pick some of them. I compared the codes that use sapply & grepl() by Sixiang.Hu, grepl() by David Arenburg, and substr by David Arenburg, it appears that the sapply code has the best performance. Your code provided in this section, however, generates many NA values. Please refer to my updates to my question. Thanks.

Comment: @MiaoCai I've added some benchmarks, see my edit. I believe your benchmarks are wrong.

Comment: Thanks. I have figured out the reason why NAs were generated, and it is updated in the orginial question. I also made a benchmark based on my data. Interestingly, my benchmark results is different from yours. sapply is not as bad as that in your benchmark results.

Answer (score 2):

I'd suggest to use regular express and then sapply for vectorizing.

```
t_test <- as.data.frame(t(test))
chk <- function(x){
  grepl("I25\\.2|I21\\.|I22\\.",x)
}

sapply(t_test,chk)
```

The return result would be true or false based, and can be easily converted to 0 or 1.

**Edit1**:
My bad that didn't notice it is row-based check. Updated the code above.

**Edit2**:
Change the regression pattern:
1. escaping the `.` using `\\`. Otherwise, single `.` means matching any character
2. changing `[]` to `|`, given `[]` means if any character in it will give a TRUE.

Comment: Won't this apply column-wise, where the OP is working row-wise?

Comment: @Sixiang.Hu Thanks for your help! The performance improves a lot by sapply. I am wondering how the function "grepl" works. When I type `grepl("[H34.0][G45]","H34.023")` it returns TRUE. However, when I type `grepl("[H34.0][G45][G46][I60][I61][I62][I63][I64][I65][I66][I67][I68][I69]","H34.023")` it returns FALSE. This causes great trouble because sometimes I need to include many sets of characters.

Comment: @MiaoCai, responce edited, for further regular expression, you can search for "r regular expression" (e.g. http://stat545.com/block022_regular-expression.html).

Comment: The by row loop here is unnecessary. You could easily vectorize this using something like `res <- grepl("I25\\.2|I21\\.|I22\\.", unlist(test)) ; dim(res) <- dim(test) ; test$MI <- rowSums(res)`

Comment: @Sixiang.Hu Thanks for your help. I saw your C.V on linkedin, and it appears that we were from the same city. I graduated from Huazhong University of Science and Technology, next to Wuhan University.

Answer (score 0):

## UPDATE 1

I compared the codes that use “sapply & grepl()” by @Sixiang.Hu, “grepl()”by @David Arenburg, and “substr” by @David Arenburg, it appears that the sapply code has the best performance. “substr” by @David Arenburg code provided in this section, however, generates many NA values. Could any explain the reason why these NA values generate?

```
> # sapply & grepl()
> start.time <- Sys.time()
> test <- subset(I61, select = c("p324", "p327", "p3291", "p3294", "p3297", "p3281", "p3284", "p3287", "p3271", "p3274"))
> MIchk <- function(x){
+   grepl("I25\\.2|I21\\.|I22\\.",x)
+ }
> test1 <- sapply(test,MIchk)
> test$MI <- rowSums(test1)
> end.time <- Sys.time()
> end.time - start.time
Time difference of 2.363007 secs
> table(test$MI,exclude = NULL)

     0      1      2   <NA> 
254495   3523     15      0 
> 
> # grepl() 
> start.time <- Sys.time()
> test <- subset(I61, select = c("p324", "p327", "p3291", "p3294", "p3297", "p3281", "p3284", "p3287", "p3271", "p3274"))
> res <- grepl("I25\\.2|I21\\.|I22\\.", unlist(test))
> dim(res) <- dim(test)
> test$MI1 <- rowSums(res)
> end.time <- Sys.time()
> end.time - start.time
Time difference of 2.51223 secs
> table(test$MI1,exclude = NULL)

     0      1      2   <NA> 
254495   3523     15      0 
> 
> # substr
> start.time <- Sys.time()
> test <- subset(I61, select = c("p324", "p327", "p3291", "p3294", "p3297", "p3281", "p3284", "p3287", "p3271", "p3274"))
> res <- (substr(unlist(test), 1, 5) == "I25.2") | (substr(unlist(test), 1, 4) %in% c("I21.", "I22."))
> dim(res) <- dim(test)
> test$MI2 <- rowSums(res)
> end.time <- Sys.time()
> end.time - start.time
Time difference of 3.473388 secs
> table(test$MI2,exclude = NULL)

     0      1      2   <NA> 
154897   2461     11 100664
```

## UPDATE 2

The reason that the substr operation generates many NA value is that my dataset contains NA values. So I performed the following codes and then the above mentioned three operations yeild consistent results:

```
library(dplyr)
test %>% mutate_if(is.factor, as.character) -> test 
test[is.na(test)]<-0
```

and then I performed the three codes:

```
> #=================================
> # sapply & grepl()
> start.time <- Sys.time()
> MIchk <- function(x){
+   grepl("I25\\.2|I21\\.|I22\\.",x)
+ }
> test1 <- sapply(test,MIchk)
> test$MI <- rowSums(test1)
> end.time <- Sys.time()
> end.time - start.time
Time difference of 5.864876 secs
> table(test$MI,exclude = NULL)

     0      1      2   <NA> 
520339   3081     21      0 
> #=================================
> # grepl() 
> start.time <- Sys.time()
> test1 <- subset(test, select = c("p324", "p327", "p3291", "p3294", "p3297", "p3281", "p3284", "p3287", "p3271", "p3274"))
> res <- grepl("I25\\.2|I21\\.|I22\\.", unlist(test1))
> dim(res) <- dim(test1)
> test$MI1 <- rowSums(res)
> end.time <- Sys.time()
> end.time - start.time
Time difference of 17.20333 secs
> table(test$MI1,exclude = NULL)

     0      1      2   <NA> 
520339   3081     21      0 
> #=================================
> # substr
> start.time <- Sys.time()
> test2 <- subset(test, select = c("p324", "p327", "p3291", "p3294", "p3297", "p3281", "p3284", "p3287", "p3271", "p3274"))
> tmp <- unlist(test2)
> res <- (substr(tmp, 1, 5) == "I25.2") | (substr(tmp, 1, 4) %in% c("I21.", "I22."))
> dim(res) <- dim(test2)
> test$MI2 <- rowSums(res)
> end.time <- Sys.time()
> end.time - start.time
Time difference of 4.386484 secs
> table(test$MI2,exclude = NULL)

     0      1      2   <NA> 
520339   3081     21      0
```

Finally, I also made a benchmark test, which shows that substr operation is slightly better than sapply/grepl and significantly better than vectorised grepl alone. Here are my codes and results:

```
#--------------------------------
SixHu <- function(df) { 
  MIchk <- function(x){
    grepl("I25\\.2|I21\\.|I22\\.",x)
  }
  test1 <- sapply(df,MIchk)
  rowSums(test1)
}
#--------------------------------
# Vectorized grepl
SixHuVec <- function(df) { 
  res <- grepl("I25\\.2|I21\\.|I22\\.", unlist(df))
  dim(res) <- dim(df) 
  rowSums(res)
}
#--------------------------------
David <- function(df) { 
  tmp <- unlist(df)
  res <- (substr(tmp, 1, 5) == "I25.2") | (substr(tmp, 1, 4) %in% c("I21.", "I22."))
  dim(res) <- dim(df)
  rowSums(res)
}
> microbenchmark::microbenchmark(SixHu(test),
                                 +                                SixHuVec(test),
                                  +                                David(test))
Unit: seconds
expr       min        lq      mean    median        uq       max neval cld
SixHu(test)  4.323772  4.598328  4.836165  4.760263  4.988194  5.801979   100  b 
SixHuVec(test) 11.867062 12.826925 13.342357 13.243638 13.635339 18.705615   100   c
David(test)  3.728264  4.180152  4.389600  4.344938  4.519908  6.396018   100 a
```

Therefore, vectorized substr() by @David Arenburg is the best answer while sapply/grepl by @Sixiang.Hu, and significantly better than grepl()by @David Arenburg. Anyway, these three methods are all much better than the loops by the OP :(. Thanks guys! @David Arenburg @Sixiang.Hu